# finding which image isn't hidden

Tags: jquery

Basically, I have two images, both hold data in which I need based on if they're hidden or not (dynamically)

Here's the two images I have :

```
<img src="images/active-arrow.jpg" alt="active" class="activeimg" id="selectedFacebook" />
<img src="images/active-arrow.jpg" alt="active" class="activeimg" id="selectedTwitter" />
```

Dynamically, via a jQuery call one of these are hidden on page load by doing the following

```
$('#selectedFacebook').hide();
```

How can I find which on isn't hidden using jQuery? something like this?

```
if(!$('#selectedFacebook').hide()) {
   //facebook is shown
} else if(!$('#selectedTwitter').hide()) {
   //twitter is shown
}
```

That's obviously not the correct syntax but how would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`:hidden`](http://api.jquery.com/hidden-selector/) selector:

```
if(!$('#selectedFacebook').is(':hidden')) {
   //facebook is shown
}

if(!$('#selectedTwitter').is(':hidden')) {
   //twitter is shown
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You want this:

```
$('#selectedFacebook').is(":visible");
```

Returns `true` if visible.

Answer (score 0):

You can check with like following e.g. how to check if image is hidden.

```
if($('#selectedFacebook').is(":hidden")) {
   console.log('yes')
} else {
  console.log('no')
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If need to get the `id` of visible element:

```
$('#selectedFacebook').hide();

var visible = $('.activeimg:visible').map(function() {
  return this.id;
}).get().join();

console.log(visible);
```

**[JSBin Demo](http://jsbin.com/egepes/1/edit)**

Answer (score -1):

```
 if($("#selectedFacebook").css("visiblity")=="hidden")){
         //facebook is shown
      }
   else if($("##selectedTwitter").css("visiblity")=="hidden")){
         //twitter is shown
   }
```